# Identifying Duplicate records from List and make separate list for duplicates and non duplicates

Tags: apex

I have a use case where i have a list of orderItems which contains duplicates let us say:

```
OrderItem:{Product2__c=01t6F0000CCXXXXXX, Id=8026F00000EqzYYYYY}, 
OrderItem:{Product2__c=01t6F00000CCXXXXXX, Id=8026F00000Eqzba2AB}, 
OrderItem:{Product2__c=01t6F00000CCXXXXXX, Id=8026F00000Eqrbs3AB}, 
OrderItem:{Product2__c=01t6F000009kSSSSSS, Id=8026F00000Eqzx1RRR}
```

here first 3 orderitems are duplicate based on the field Product2__c so i want to make a seperate list of id's for duplicate records and unique records i have tried n implemented the below code but its not working as expected.

```
 List<OrderItem> ListOI = new List<OrderItem>();<br/>
Set<String> DuplicateId = new Set<String>();<br/>
List<OrderItem> Item = [Select Id,Product2__c from Orderitem where OrderId =:OrderMap.keySet()];<br/>
        for(OrderItem itemm : Item)
         {
             if(!DuplicateId.contains(itemm.Product2__c ))
             {
                 ListOI.add(itemm);
                 DuplicateId.add(itemm.Id);
             } else {
                 DuplicateId.add(itemm.Id);
             }
         }
```

can any one suggest me how to implement this in proper way

Comment: @identigral thanks for your response the link which you have send is absolutely valid but if you look at my issue duplication i am checking for the field "Product2__c" and i want to fetch that "Id" of that duplicate record in a seperate list.

Comment: Can you explain what you are expecting to happen versus what is actually happening?

Comment: @zach i am expecting that what ever duplicate records are there based on "Product2__c" i want to fetch that record "Id" in a seperate list.

Comment: What's not working as expected?

Comment: @zach the logic which i mentioned fetches the product id for which i cannot perform the update activity so i require the "Id" field value  of that duplicate records to perform further operation. if not any other approach is also fine as my approach may be wrong.

Comment: Okay, so you're getting DML errors when you are trying to update a record? Are you able to see a specific error message?

Comment: @zach i cannot perform at all DML operatoin using product2__c field i need ID field value to perform DML Operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
Set<String> DuplicateId = new Set<String>();
Map<Id,OrderItem> uniqueItem = new map<Id,ordereditem >;

        for(OrderItem itemm : [Select Id,Product2__c from Orderitem where OrderId  in :OrderMap.keySet()])
         {
             if(!uniqueItem.containsKey(itemm.Product2__c ))
             {
                 UniqueItem.put(itemm.Product2__c,itemm);
                 
             } else {
                 DuplicateId.add(itemm.Id);
             }
         }
```

Then use the values to get the unique ones